# Active Batch - Download Files from SFTP filtered by File Name

Tags: file, transfer, managed, activebatch

im trying to download files using managed file transfer and filter the files based on the file name, however the filter option does not have the file patter option. Is there any way to implement download files filtered by file name?

[image]

Thanks for the help!

i have tried using variables but it did not worked